# Click to dial functionality went missing on switching to Lightning Experience

Tags: lightning, cti, call-center

I am having a call center and click to dial enabled in Salesforce, However, the click to dial functionality is missing when I switch to Lightning Experience.

Can anyone please help?[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the Call Center feature you might need to switch to a new feature when using lightning. I found this documentation from Salesforce that says there is an app called Open CTI for Lightning Experience, so you might want to looking into that if you want to have the Click to Dial feature in Lightning Experience.

Documentation Link: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cti_overview.htm&type=0&language=en_US